# Why isn't this code highlighting?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

Why does the first block of code get highlighted but not the second one?  Is the second code block being interpreted as part of the second list item?  If so, how do I close the second list item so I can start marking code with only 4 spaces?

```
Sub HereIsSomeCode()

End Sub
```

1. First list item.
2. Next list item.

   Sub HereIsSomeCode()

   End Sub

   ```
   (code prefixed by 8 spaces)
   Sub HereIsSomeCode()

   End Sub
   ```